# How to use repeater with ArrayList multiple value as one tr in multiple td?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

[image: Web page layout]I was given a web form, which show the product name and price, I choose the product and quantity ,click add button and it will keep updating my choice below.

I tried to use multi dimentional array but it won't show anything in the repeater, ArrayList is the same

Repeater code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate><table></HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td> <%# GetDataItem()%> </td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


public partial class Link : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   static ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
        Repeater1.DataSource = arrList;
        Repeater1.DataBind();         
    }
```

Button event handler function

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        Label2.Text = Session["email"].ToString();

        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                qty1+=Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
                total1 = qty1 * price1;
                lblQty1.Text=""+qty1;
                lblTotal1.Text = ""+total1;
                arrList.Add("Product One");
                arrList.Add(qty1);
                arrList.Add(total1);
                break;
```

I am expecting, if I type correct quantity, the ArrayList can save my product name, quantity and calculated price.and update as one row with three s , if i add second item, it should add the second record as well, if the product is already there, it will add the quantity automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this below code

```
  <table>
    <tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td> <%# GetDataItem()%> </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You should repeat the td instead of repeating the tr since doing that will result in a new row created everytime when a loop iterates.